# No network adapters after upgrading Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, network-adapter, windows-10-upgrade

Today I installed the latest version of Windows 10 (kind of a major update I think). After the update I had no internet or network connection.

- Looking at the network adapter list in system control, it was completly empty
- However when looking at the list of network adapters in the device manager I could see all my virtual and pysical network adapters, however all of them had an yellow exclamation mark on them

Is there any way to fix this without rolling back my windows installation?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me. I noticed that every adapter also had the yellow exclamation mark, BUT ONE.

It was the "Checkpoint VPN Adapter".

After uninstalling the Checkpoint VPN software through normal system control panel, right after the uninstall finished all other adapters came to life immediately.

If this happens to someone else, maybe just look out for the single one adapter that does not have the exclamation mark and try to uninstall the corresponding software.

Comment: We certainly appreciate you sharing your knowledge with the community by posting a good question **and** the associated answer!  However, it may be a bit silly to actually say *"I had the same problem and for me..."* when it is already apparent that you are talking to yourself.  Just something to consider.

Comment: @Run5k Yeah right. Thought it would better fit QA style ;)